# Are there qgis equivalent to Cogo tools of ArcView 3.2

Tags: qgis-plugins, arcview-3, cogo

We are  transistioning to Qgis, i have GIS users that currently use ArcView 3.2 (yes there are still people using this) they find the cogo tools very useful and I was wondering if there is an equivalent tool in QGIS 1.8?

Answer (score 1):

There is an Azimuth and Distance Plugin [in the official repository](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAzimuth/version/0.8.6/). You should be able to install it using the plugin installer.

I have not used it. But from [this post](http://www.northrivergeographic.com/archives/lost-my-bearing-found-it-in-qgis), it seems it would do your requirement.

Comment: Thanks millions for your response!!! i'll try the plugin